# ejabberd oom_killer configuration

Tags: ejabberd

I am running an *ejabberd* machine for sending application to application data through XMPP, but recently, with upgrading from *ejabberd* 16 to latest 18.04-0, *ejabberd* is closing a process with the message: `Killed 1 process(es) consuming more than 38108 message(s) each`.

I researched this issue and [found](https://blog.process-one.net/ejabberd-17-12/) that in *ejabberd* 17.12 they have optimized the `oom_killer`.

My machine has 12G of RAM and dedicated to run only ejabberd, there is 7G free memory and it still kills the process.

I looked in the [source](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/ejabberd_system_monitor.erl) on line `275`, is the culprit method, but I notice that it has a parameter "threshold" that it checks against, but I can't find anything on it in the docs. Is it possible to configure it ? Right now I had to set the "oom_killer: false" to overcome this issue, but it will bite me back later I suspect (*note: it was a bad idea, server ended up swapping in the end*).

I am far from being an expert on erlang or ejabberd, any advice to either optimize memory usage or `oom_killer` would be welcome.

=== edit ===

I forgot to mention I am running it on Ubuntu 16.04 x64 (virtual machine on vmware).

== update day 2 ==

What I can find from the logs:
crash.log:

```
2018-05-15 15:01:40 =ERROR REPORT====
Killed 1 process(es) consuming more than 15112 message(s) each2018-05-15 15:47:35 =ERROR REPORT====
Killed 1 process(es) consuming more than 27255 message(s) each2018-05-15 17:58:02 =ERROR REPORT====
Killed 1 process(es) consuming more than 11686 message(s) each2018-05-15 18:46:12 =ERROR REPORT====
Killed 1 process(es) consuming more than 42388 message(s) each2018-05-16 07:43:31 =ERROR REPORT====
Killed 1 process(es) consuming more than 47615 message(s) each2018-05-17 13:47:16 =ERROR REPORT====
backend port not found: inotifywait
```

and ejabberd.log basically just repeats one line of that like I showed before and then nothing else.
Thing is, ejabber itself keeps running, but there is one VERY busy room that becomes inaccessible after this crash message (safe to assume its this room that crashes?).
I will run ejabberd in debug to hopefully get a bit more info on that.

I have found in the meantime that this memory issue is not present in ejabberd 17.01 or earlier.

I don't have this issue with the Ubuntu repo ejabberd which is 16.01 or the 17.01 version from ProcessOne, versions I tested and that had the issue where 17.12 (17.12 had a confirmed mem leak though that was fixed in 18.01) and 18.04.

anyway i'm stumped and I am out of ideas on how to debug.

== update day 3 ==

I have found no solution to the memory problems with ejabberd 18.04, but I will try out FreeBSD and Ubuntu 18.04 next week.

I have also come to the conclusion that my entire code architecture is at fault here.

To clarify the situation, I am collecting information from different sources, process that info and save it to a database using bots written in python and bots communicate over xmpp.
One bot reads the data and sends to a room, there the next bot reads the data and adds new information, next one validates and sends to collection room.

Since there are many sources and the end point for all of them is the same where an archiver tries to then save them to mongo, meaning the collection room process gets thousands of messages per minute.

The thing is, all the info ends up in one room before saving, I guess the archive process isn't able to read the messages fast enough and "something" happens that ends with the memory issue and crash.

Ejabberd has its internal processes and is able to handle many thousands of them easily as I understand, but I guess I am not leveraging that and instead cram everything into one process in the end.

So I will see if getting rid of this collection room process will help speed everything.

Will keep updating, maybe my experimentation helps someone else.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Quite a good question for a begginer. Just make sure you format your questions as well as possible next time so they are easier to read. Here's your upvote, good luck.

Comment: A process overloaded with 38k messages is not normal. Furthermore, in practice such huge process overload is *very* likely the point of no return: if you don't kill it, it will eventually consume the whole memory. Also, it would be helpful to see the exact message ejabberd is logging, i.e. to know what process is acting like this.

Comment: jup, that was what happened when oom_killer was disabled. I hoped, that it would stabilize at some point, but no luck.

Comment: > basically just repeats one line of that like I showed before and then nothing else

That's because you set too low log level. Set loglevel to 4 (info), no need to do it debug. In the majority of cases "info" loglevel is the correct level.

> safe to assume its this room that crashes?

Very likely, yes. Find that room and inspect it: the number of participants, the ban/member list size, the message routing pattern, etc.

Comment: Gosh, I hate stackoverflow editing.

Comment: Well, I ran it in debug, no enlightenment, I am quite sure I ran it in info before and that message is all I saw, I will recheck it though to be absolutely sure.

Comment: I am now running the entire system using ejabberd 16.01 with no memory issues and crashes, I send about 2800 messages per minute to the room. Ejabberd 18.04-0 crashes under that load.